# How to rotate all the keyframes of root bone?

Tags: animation, bones

I found an animated character online. I want to rotate this character for all the keyframes by 180 degrees along the Z-axis. This can be done by rotating the root bone. But how do I go about rotating the root bone for all keyframes?

The animation use quaternion rotation.

Here's the [.fbx](https://mixamo-storage-prod.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/system/tmp/export_41921a38-7ba6-4833-9cb2-f532fb1920d0.fbx?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22Stand%20Up.fbx%22&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQYKQKDRYXVSCAALU%2F20200527%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200527T081242Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEGAaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJGMEQCIDvW5kRSPiVstJ8fzsa51HTQNVf%2FXEg6VQg5TjWqf0KhAiAebnnPDR%2FDOkMcewL57qqiT%2BHbAzXG0Vv47fjIlJD0xiq9Awi5%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1MjI0NDkxMzI2NSIMWuAQYDx0rTKE9mcQKpEDfsHpb98uYemYhnRWCYxV%2FVrK7JzaJA44h5%2FK7GPBS6Y%2BzVIhsV09SXN4Af3Z7DZ8qqc9vqDvu93PKO1tHes2PaFYwtVaMTwN5%2F6LtzYoG4eIsqaEBSxrXsiKPp0HXolJxzUM9p9qgs473nJ%2B8qlThnJHzw8C6hhAbKmhpmn2O5Ia5Gcn5VHaeoVGo9GY%2FIyUxYOZhIb5Qfk0z1D0uz69RCUatXZwEALqM%2B2FoAvq9CgyNE20vpQIJVdunBBBgA85DTIMcmnvYSV0Xb%2BqaN0KWCAcTgYUUQDIUUB41j8WypjlW%2BejxiO4mIaiEsuSB25nuER9CokEjlNuUpKZKZXgU5Q3qEJO1XTSk3VA1WewIdXXhr0dr90vQoApRJg6U7IhTK2NxfJ9yJYwjGIKb2c0krnEQSjbG7aReubyr%2FiBH0ABQH5297YahgR3qbt2nhZH1Jt%2BWyEZu6ntRtPnrh8iHIqfxHKbLMi%2BP0i%2Bw8ZORISE4zlH%2B5JfgIAGxTIObRy3y86O9RUQSDHBOI5ZXB1GCZcw07q49gU67AHyz%2BZl%2FHnHzsRK2EHjnwB5E7MVC92uR8Dvk%2FsclUXT4HtI4rHatX0edBPKnnzVQiddWrWfNAdGcGn1L6ofryKS3nsj38DSrbs4vK7rBlzU4W5SmcEca8Yn9QiQ%2FZDmn7mFEO91%2BdqHmUzrgX5Xfdi8PNKFzxHBR%2FibS3fJwF727oUnpdtDlEEEZGaBXunbwScf5pDOMpqZ9R8vwofYrXu35PNkmnAizSjBJ%2BB8DswhopXVYRIA3i5Qk8c0F68bO2EKhyLZonGHqN0gyF1wHXshjW6tb0wBy%2BmZ9CNHxJqEfeSqt%2BgIRr2ag0KSRw%3D%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=19e5af5a92fe8b5ede434c37561166714bec72c0bbbea54cc10c43e5a96f70f8) file

Comment: Provide more information about it. What rotation model it uses, Quaternions or Euler? What animation does root bone already have, is it moving?

Comment: It uses quaternion rotation. Yes the bone is moving

Comment: your link doesn't work. Have you tried in the Graph Editor?

Comment: Ok, i'll reupload the link, maybe it was a temporary link

Comment: @moonboots Yes i tried graph editor. It was a mess. I want rotation of 180 degrees. But the rotations of the armature are in quaternions

Comment: Btw I just solved the problem, I'll post answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my comment to @Crantisz's answer

> I have tried this and I know that it works for the armature. The
>   problem is that I am using this armature to control mesh which is not
>   directly parented to this armature through NLA. And when I try this
>   method the mesh follows the original motion without rotation

This problem arises because, when using above method the main armature only copies the actions of other armatures but preserve its object properties.

So to solve this problem I inserted a LocRotScale keyframe in the beginning and at `frame - 1` where I want rotation. This prevents unnecessary transformations. Now I rotated the main armature and insert LocRotScale keyframe. This does the job for me

Comment: Amazingly, this worked for me.  Very simple compared to what I was trying.  If you're using the NLA don't forget to specify "extropolation = hold" on the track that contains the "frame -1" pre-seed keyframe. (select the track and press "n" and then set the property).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this - it just rotate all armature as object. To do this:

- Make sure, that you select armature in object mode. If you are in Pose mode, switch to object.
- Then rotate object as you need.

Also, you can add new root bone, and parent "old root bone" to the new one. In this case you can use it to position and rotate all bones in pose mode.

Comment: I have tried this and I know that it works for the armature. The problem is that I am using this armature to control mesh which is not directly parented to this armature through NLA. And when I try this method the mesh follows the original motion without rotation

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this, but would delta keyframes be the answer here? Sadly, I can't figure out how they work.